# Select as alternative to Nested if/else in R?

Tags: r

I have some R code that works, but it is pretty damned inelegant. I was hoping I could replace all of these nested 'ifelse' statements with a switch? Does anyone have a suggestion of what that would look like for multiple conditional arguments? Looking for something analogous to 'select' in SAS.

```
ifelse((is.na(var1) & is.na(var2) & (var3 %in% 1 | 0)), resultused <- "July",
   ifelse((is.na(var1) & is.na(var2) & var3 %in% 0), resultused <- "July",
    ifelse((var1 %in% 0 & is.na(var2) & var3 %in% 1), resultused <- "July",
      ifelse((var1 %in% 0 & var2 %in% 0 & var3 %in% 1), resultused <- "July",
        ifelse((var1 %in% 0 & var2 %in% 0 & var3 %in% 0 & 
          var4 %in% 1 & var5 %in% 0 & var6 %in% 0
          & years %in% c(2,3,4)), resultused <-"July",
ifelse((is.na(var1) & (var2 %in% 0 | 1) & is.na(var3)), resultused <-"Dec",
  ifelse((is.na(var1) & (var2 %in% 0 | 1) & var3 %in% 0), resultused <- "Dec",
    ifelse((var1 %in% 0 & var2 %in% 1 & is.na(var3)), resultused <- "Dec",
      ifelse((var1 %in% 0 & var2 %in% 1 & var3 %in% 0), resultused <- "Dec",
        ifelse((is.na(var4) & (var5 %in% 0 | 1) & is.na(var6)), resultused <- "Dec",
          ifelse((var4 %in% 0 & (var5 %in% 0 | 1) & is.na(var6)
                  & (is.na(years) | years %in% c(5, 6))), resultused <- "Dec",
ifelse(((var1 %in% 0 | 1) & is.na(var2) & is.na(var3)), resultused <- "May",
  ifelse(((var1 %in% 0 | 1) & var2 %in% 0 & is.na(var3)), resultused <- "May", 
    ifelse(((var1 %in% 0 | 1) & var2 %in% 0 & var3 %in% 0), resultused <- "May",
      ifelse((var1 %in% 1 & is.na(var2) & var3 %in% 1), resultused <- "May",
        ifelse((var1 %in% 1 & var2 %in% 1 & var3 %in% 0), resultused <- "May",
          ifelse((var1 %in% 1 & var2 %in% 1 & is.na(var3)), resultused <- "May", 
            ifelse(((var1 %in% 0 | 1) & is.na(var2) & var3 %in% 0), resultused <- "May", 
                    NA))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Maybe it is better if you post a compact version of your problem that just explains the issue because honestly I think that very few users will spend time to understand this huge and complicated series of nested `ifelse`.

Comment: Thanks SabDeM. I would like to see if I can replace the following with a switch: `ifelse(is.na(var1) & is.na(var2) & (var3 %in% 1 | 0), result, ifelse...)` with a `switch`. Hopefully the above code does show how cumbersome the nested `ifelse` can get. The code works, it just seems unnecessarily bulky and inelegant.

Comment: like this: http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/switch ?  You might make a stack of variables like "case1 <- isna(var2) & (var3 %in% 1 | 0)" then at the end of the case list have "myswitch(case1, case2, case3)"

Comment: and please provide some sample data to understand the content of the variables "var*" better...

Comment: All variables are `as.factor` with levels `0` or `1` except `years` which is `as.numeric` and `resultused` which is `as.character`.

Comment: side note: (var1 %in% 1 | 0 ) does not do what you probably think.  It is logically equivalent to (var1 == 1).  Perhaps you mean (var1 %in% 0:1)

Comment: @EngrStudent Thank you that is very helpful!

Comment: @Rick, thank you you may be right. I'm trying to get `var1 == 1` OR `var1==0`

Comment: Would a "Truth Table" show what you're trying to do more clearly?

Comment: @Rick I tried it as `(var1 %in% 0:1)` and that gave me the right output. Thank you. And thanks to @SabDeM @RYoda and @EngrStudent for the helpful comments as well. I think the `switch` in `base` will do the trick and make this a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this: [inside-r.org/r-doc/base/switch](http://inside-r.org/r-doc/base/switch)

You might make a stack of variables like "case1 <- isna(var2) & (var3 %in% 1 | 0)" then at the end of the case list have "myswitch(case1, case2, case3)

Best of luck